# Prove $f(x)$ is a probability density

Tags: probability, integration, density-function

let $f$ and $g$ be two continuous functions from $[a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ such that $f(a) = g(a), f(b) = g(b)$ and $f(s) \gt g(s)$ for $s \in (a,b)$.

If $f(x)$ has distribution $\left(\frac{f(x) - g(x)}{\int_a^b f(t) - g(t) dt}\right)$ for $x \in [a,b]$ prove $f(x)$ is a probability density.

I understand we need to show $f(x) \ge 0$ and $\int_a^b f(x) dx = 1$ but i'm struggling to show the latter requirement.

Comment: A note on notation: we denote integrating from $a$ to $b$ by $\int_{a}^{b}$, not $\int_{b}^{a}$. The lower limit of integration goes on the bottom.

Comment: "If $f(x)$ has distribution ..." Should it be "If $h(x)$ has distribution ...", using new function?

Answer (score 2):

You are confused
because you use
$f(x)$ in two ways:
as one of the functions
(along with $g(x)$)
and as the name of the
distribution function.

You should use a different name like this:

If $h(x)$
has distribution
$\left(\frac{f(x) - g(x)}{\int_b^a f(t) - g(t) dt}\right)
$,
show that
$h$ is a distribution function.

This then becomes easy:

$\begin{array}\\
\int_a^b h(x) dx
&=\int_a^b \left(\frac{f(x) - g(x)}{\int_b^a (f(t) - g(t)) dt}dx\right)\\
&=\frac1{\int_b^a (f(t) - g(t)) dt}\int_a^b (f(x) - g(x))dx\\
&=1\\
\end{array}
$